# How to detect and prevent screen locking when power button is pressed in windows mobile phone 6?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6

In my windows mobile phone 6 application, I want to detect the power button press event and prevent it from locking my phone screen. Is it possible in windows mobile phone 6?  Can anybody please guide me on this?

Answer (score 0):

capturing the power button may impossible for your need. Although there is a keyboard message with VK_OFF, it is mostly not exposed to applications. You may try a keyboard hook (see my web site) to capture VK_OFF, but I fear you will not be able to capture VK_OFF. Mostly the power button is something hard linked to the mainboard and/or a special DLL.

When you say, you want to keep the power button to lock your phone, there may be another solution, if either a application is called or VK_LOCK is used by the OS.

It would be easier to give a suggestion, if you can post a snapshot (look for SSNAP by SK Tools) of the device's registry and file system.

regards

Josef